# Python Global Variable inside Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables, global

I need help to explain the following behaviour, Why x is a global variable?

```
def y():

    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x=5
    a = y()
```

output:
`5`

Comment: because you're setting it in the global scope. the "if" statement doesn't change that fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

doesn't define a new/local scope. It's designed to protect execution of the below block from happening when the module is imported by another module.

So defining `x` within this block makes it global, and it works because you're calling the function *after* having defined it.

note that importing this very module and calling `y` from there will raise an error because the definition of `x` won't be executed